# How to remove multiple duplicate rows from table without using row numbering in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Lets say I have a table with the following records:

```
| Participant_ID | VISITNUM | col1 | col2 | col3 |
|----------------|----------|------|------|------|
| 1              | 1        | ADA  | 3.2  | 1.7  |
| 1              | 2        | MJT  | 3.1  | 1.6  |
| 2              | 1        | LRM  | 4.1  | 2.2  |
| 2              | 1        |      | 4.1  | 2.2  |
| 2              | 2        | TPS  | 3.9  | 2.4  |
| 2              | 3        |      | 3.3  | 2.6  |
| 2              | 3        | MJT  | 3.3  | 2.6  |
| 2              | 4        | BLL  | 3.6  | 2.5  |
| 2              | 4        | BLL  | 3.6  | 2.5  |
```

You can see above that there are multiple "visit" records (`VISITNUM`) for each participant (`Participant_ID`).  In some cases, there are multiple duplicate "visits" for some participants.  I can't use `SELECT DISTINCT` because in some cases the records might have a `NULL` value in one of the duplicate records (see `col1` blanks).

I am also having trouble applying windowing and/or `CTE's` to this situation because it only removes the first duplicate [`Participant_ID`],[`VISITNUM`] and won't address additional duplicates within the same partition of [`Participant_ID`].

The output I want would be something like this:

```
| Participant_ID | VISITNUM | col1 | col2 | col3 |
|----------------|----------|------|------|------|
| 1              | 1        | ADA  | 3.2  | 1.7  |
| 1              | 2        | MJT  | 3.1  | 1.6  |
| 2              | 1        | LRM  | 4.1  | 2.2  |
| 2              | 2        | TPS  | 3.9  | 2.4  |
| 2              | 3        |      | 3.3  | 2.6  |
| 2              | 4        | BLL  | 3.6  | 2.5  |
```

...where it returns only unique [`Participant_ID`],[`VISITNUM`] records and leaves the duplicates out. I am not concerned about the data in `col1`, whether it returns the duplicate record with the data or the NULL.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you can't use `ROW_NUMBER` here, you just need the correct columns in the `PARTITION BY`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Participant_ID, VisitNum ORDER BY VisitNum)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT  Participant_ID,
        VISITNUM,
        col1,
        col2,
        col3
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Wow, yep rookie mistake.  I did not include Visitnum in my partition statement, only in the order by.  I can't believe I missed that.  Thank you, this works!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Participant_ID, VISITNUM
                                order by (select NULL)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You seem to want one row per `Participant_ID`/`VISITNUM` pair, which is what this returns.

Comment: You are correct, I made a silly mistake.  I was not including visitnum in my partition by statement, only in the order by.  I really appreciate the help, I am still learning.  Thanks!